# UITableView + 2 Custom Cells = Wrong with heights

Tags: ios, height, tableview, cell

I have a UITableView which should show news.
I did set up 2 custom cells -> one has the news without an image, and the other one has the news with image.
So the cells need different heights. In storyboard I created those 2 Cells and they each have a custom height (280 with image, 130 without).

For testing purposes I want the first and the third cell to be a news cell + image.
So thats my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSDictionary * news = [postArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //PostArray is the array with the news
NSDictionary *authorData = [news valueForKey:@"author"];


NSString *postTitle = [self decodedString:[news valueForKey:@"title"]]; 
//Decode = change html chars
NSString *postExcerpt = [self decodedString:[news valueForKey:@"excerpt"]];
NSString *postComments = [news valueForKey:@"comment_count"];
//NSString *postID = [news valueForKey:@"id"];


NSString *authorFirstName = [self decodedString:[authorData valueForKey:@"first_name"]];
NSString *authorLastName = [self decodedString:[authorData valueForKey:@"last_name"]];
NSString *authorNickName = [self decodedString:[authorData valueForKey:@"nickname"]];

if (indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 2){



    NewsCellImage *cell = (NewsCellImage *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsCellImage"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[NewsCellImage alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"NewsCellImage"];

    }


    // Set up the cell
    cell.postTitle.text = postTitle;
    cell.postExcerpt.text = postExcerpt;
    cell.postCommentsCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row];

    //Check if names are empty
    if ([authorFirstName length] == 0 && [authorLastName length] == 0){
        cell.postMeta.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@",authorNickName,[news valueForKey:@"date"]];
    } else {
        cell.postMeta.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ / %@",authorFirstName,authorLastName,[news valueForKey:@"date"]];
    }

    //Set Image
    NSDictionary *imageData = [news valueForKey:@"thumbnail_images"];
    NSDictionary *imageDataFull = [imageData valueForKey:@"large"];
    NSString *postImage = [imageDataFull valueForKey:@"url"];


    [cell.postImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postImage]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu"]
                          completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                              if (error){
                                  NSLog(@"Error bei Bild laden: %@",postTitle);
                              }

                          } usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];



    return cell;
} else {

    NewsCell *cell = (NewsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[NewsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"NewsCell"];

    }


    // Set up the cell
    cell.postTitle.text = postTitle;
    cell.postExcerpt.text = postExcerpt;
    cell.postCommentsCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",postComments];

    //Check if names are empty
    if ([authorFirstName length] == 0 && [authorLastName length] == 0){
        cell.postMeta.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@",authorNickName,[news valueForKey:@"date"]];
    } else {
        cell.postMeta.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ / %@",authorFirstName,authorLastName,[news valueForKey:@"date"]];
    }



    return cell;
}


}
```

The code does work in general and thats what I can see after starting the app:
http://cl.ly/image/320K1y081T3Z

But when I scroll down to the next cell with Image something goes wrong:
http://cl.ly/image/2M2O1X3R2T13

So something is wrong with my code or I need to add something - but I dont know which way to take.

Maybe it's something with

```
  -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath{ }
```

But I really dont know. I appreciate help. Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does your:

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath{ }
```

look then?

I think you need something like:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath{
if (indexpath.row == 0 || indexpath.row == 2) {
    return 280;
}
return 130;
```

}

Comment: Ok, then I will use that, thought there was another way or something messed up with my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this method.

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath{ 

if (indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 2){
 return newsWithImageHeight; 
}
 else  return newsHeight; 


}
```

Or you can check autolayout setting for cell in interfacebuilder

Comment: Thanks, I would mark boths responses as the right solution, but I will ofc upvote yours :)